# Parse JSON with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am trying to parse a JSON result with AJAX.

My JSON looks like this

```
[{
        "_id" : "54fb09b7d059bdf3107f9486",
        "lastName" : "Record",
        "firstName" : "First",
        "__v" : 0
    }, {
        "_id" : "54fb0a2fd059bdf3107f9487",
        "lastName" : "Record",
        "firstName" : "First",
        "__v" : 0
    }
]
```

I call this in Javascript

```
$.getJSON('api/people', function(data) {
       item3="+data.item3+"</p>");


  $.each(data,function(i,j){
    content ='<span>'+j[i].firstName+'<br />'+j[i].lastName+'<br /></span>';
  });
        alert(content);
  });
```

Unfortunately I get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstName' of undefined" in the console.

Can someone please tell me how to properly parse this JSON?

Comment: The posted code actually doesn't reach the `$.each` because there is a syntax error. That being said, `j.firstName` is what you want. `$.getJSON` parses the `responseText` for you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`jQuery.each`'s second argument (the function executed for each element) takes two arguments (in your example, `i` and `j`), the first representing the **key** and the second the **value**, so there's no need for `j[i]`.

This should work:

```
$.getJSON('api/people', function(data) {
  $.each(data,function(i, item){
    content ='<span>'+item.firstName+'<br />'+item.lastName+'<br /></span>';
  });
  alert(content);
});
```